# Previous method still writing data to text file while the new instance of the method is running C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I am currently facing an issue, I have a method that I run which queries specific ports of a server and writes the results to a text file called temp.txt. Temp.txt should never have any duplicate data in - the file should be clear before the method begins, although sometimes I find that the previous instance of the method is still running (as its asynchronous) and I often get duplicate data since the other method is still writing to the file / performing the queries.

Code Snippet:

```
            StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText("temp");
            sw.WriteLine("Check1=Success");
            sw.Close();
```

Comment: The problem isn't with writing to the file, it's the way your calling the code that writes the file asynchronously. Either you do it synchronously or you lock access so only one thread can do it at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement some sort of [lock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

> Lock ensures that one thread does not enter a critical section of
>   code while another thread is in the critical section. **If another
>   thread attempts to enter a locked code, it will wait, block, until the
>   object is released.**

```
  class OnlyOneCallerAllowed
    {     
       private static readonly object locker = new object();        
        public static void OnlyOneMethodCanWrite()
        {
           lock (locker)
            {
             using(StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText("temp"))
             {
               sw.WriteLine("Check1=Success");
             }

         }
     }
```

Comment: Something like this is the most likely solution. Access to the file needs to be limited to one thread at a time. We could do with a bit more code and an explanation of what you are attempting to achieve by writing to the file Peter.

Answer (score 2):

I would prefer change the approach. Use a queue to record that you need to update the file. Could be an MSMQ or an in mmemory queue, depending on what level of fault tolerance you want to have. Then **have a single thread to dequeue that evants and update the file**, with this you guarantee single updates. This is a sort of implementation o the publish-subscribe pattern, with many publisher and a single subscriber. Alternatively you can lock the file access by using a `lock()` over a static object.

Answer (score 0):

```
StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText("temp");
sw.WriteLine("Check1=Success");
sw.Flush(); // <======
sw.Close();
```

---

**EDIT**:

What about opening the file with exclusive access (`FileShare.None`)?

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream("temp", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
```

You will need to do introduce some error handling as well, since you will get an exception, if the other method is still having the file open.

Comment: This wont help. Your problem is that two things are writing to the file at once. Flushing it wont solve that.